# Length error when trying to check if value exists in another pandas column

Tags: python, pandas

I want to return a column `Scoring Site` that reflects `P2 Actual Scan Site`, but only when `P2 Actual Scan Site` is considered valid.

Inputs:

A dataframe `sites_exams_df` including a column that checks for validity `Valid Site for Exam?`, like this:

```
      SCI    DBN4 Valid Site for Exam?
0      NaN  02L298                  NaN
1      NaN  02L416                  NaN
2      NaN  02L420                  NaN
3   SCI,    02L475               02L475
```

My current dataframe with `P2 Actual Scan Site`:

```
P2 Actual Scan Site
0         -
1    10L445
2    10L445
3    02L475
4    02L475
5    27L400
6    00000C
```

Desired Output:

```
  P2 Actual Scan Site  Scoring Site
0                   -           NaN      
1              10L445        10L445
2              10L445        10L445
3              02L475        02L475
4              02L475        02L475      
5              27L400        27L400
6              00000C           NaN
```

Note that the last school code returns a NaN because it's not considered a valid site (as well as the `-`).

All the other school codes return just as they are.

Current code:

```python
# create Scoring Site column
sites_exams_df['Valid Site for Exam?'] = np.where(sites_exams_df[exam].notnull(),sites_exams_df['DBN4'],
                                                  np.nan) # check what scoring sites are there for this exam
valid_sites = sites_exams_df['Valid Site for Exam?'].dropna().values

# attempt 1
df['Scoring Site'] = np.where(df['P2 Actual Scan Site'] in valid_sites,
                              df['P2 Actual Scan Site'],np.nan)

# attempt 2
df['Scoring Site'] = df.apply(lambda x: df['P2 Actual Scan Site'] if x in valid_sites else np.nan)
```

Both give me length errors:

attempt 1 - 
`raise ValueError("Lengths must match to compare")
ValueError: Lengths must match to compare`

attempt 2 -
`ValueError: ('Lengths must match to compare', 'occurred at index DBN - Exam')`

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem:

```
# create Scoring Site column
sites_exams_df['Valid Site for Exam?'] = np.where(sites_exams_df[exam].notnull(),sites_exams_df['DBN4'],
                                                  np.nan) # check what scoring sites are there for this exam
valid_sites = list(sites_exams_df['Valid Site for Exam?'].dropna())

df['Scoring Site'] = df['P2 Actual Scan Site'].map(lambda x: x if x in valid_sites else np.nan)
```

map is the operation that should be used.